# Image Overlay jQuery - Get Image to Stay on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am using the following code to display an overlay image when the base-image is hovered over:

```
$(".roll").css("opacity","0"); 
$(".roll").show();
// on mouseover
$(".roll").hover(function () {
  var s = $(this).siblings('img');
  var w = s.css("width");
  var h = s.css("height");

$(this).css("height",h).css("width",w).stop().animate({
   opacity: .6 }, 
   "fast");
 },
// on mouseout
function () {
   $(this).stop().animate({
     opacity: 0
    }, "fast");
 });
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
 <a class="image"  href="#">
        <span class="roll" style="display:none;"></span>
        <img src="mypic.png" class="image">
 </a>
```

**How do I implement an "on click" event, so that when the image is clicked, the overlay remains** instead of disappearing upon mouseout.

I've gotten started with the following, but not sure what else to do:

```
 $('.roll').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
       $(this).removeClass("selected");
       // remove overlay here?
    }
    else if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
       $(this).addClass("selected");
       // add overlay here?
    }
 });
```

Probably easy, but I'm not sure how to carry it out beyond the basic mouseover/mouseout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prevent on mouse out function when img has not class selected like

```
//on mouseout
function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected"))
    {
       $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
       });
    }
}
```

Means you have to check in mouseover/out function that: your images has already clicked or not?

- **Onmouseover**:if not already clicked(**Selected**) then add overlay
- **Onmouseout**: if not already clicked(**Selected**) then remove overlay

Comment: any other help would be appreciated from my side thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the overlay image to receive the click event, or the base image?  I'm going to assume the base image, but the implementation should be basically the same.

```js
// declare a flag in the outer scope
var stickImage = false;
$(".roll").css("opacity", "0");
$(".roll").show();
// on mouseover
$(".roll").hover(function() {
    var s = $(this).siblings('img');
    var w = s.css("width");
    var h = s.css("height");

    $(this).css("height", h).css("width", w).stop().animate({
        opacity: .6
    }, "fast");
});

// on click, toggle the stickImage boolean
$(".roll").click(function() {
    stickImage = !stickImage;
});

// on mouseout
function() {
    // check to make sure stickimage is false before hiding
    if (!stickImage) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, "fast");
    }
});
```